# When I open a .sql file it doesn't recognize my old tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm quite new in SQL. I am using it through SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio.

I loaded a table and worked with it doing some easy operations (select, update and so on) and then I saved my query as 'Giocatori'. Now I open it again but I am not able to run the instructions I used before saving my file for the first time. The system shows: "The object name 'Giocatori' is not valid".

I guess it's something easy, but it puts me in trouble.

Thank you so much

Comment: Make sure you have selected the correct database (default is Master). In SSMS, there is a dropdown box in the upper left corner.

Comment: Write `use <DATABASE_NAME>; GO` as the first line of your script so that you won't have to select database each time.

Comment: Great! It works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! :)